# Using sscanf() to output only 2 tokens from a line

Tags: c, scanf

I need to write a program that takes input line at a time and output **only the lines** that have two tokens.  Assume input is no longer than 50 bytes.  I used fgets to capture one line at a time and used sscanf to grab token at a time and see if it returns 2.  However, it doesn't seem to work.  Can someone suggest how to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[50];
    char token[50];
    int number;

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        while ((number = sscanf(buff, "%s", token)) != EOF)
        {
            number = sscanf(buff, "%s", token);
            if (number == 2)
            {
                printf("%s\t", token);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do `sscanf("%s%s%s") == 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[50];
    char token1[50];
    char token2[50];
    char token3[50];

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL)
    {

        if (sscanf(buff, "%s%s%s", token1, token2, token3) == 2)
        {
            printf("%s %s\n", token1, token2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this -

```
number = sscanf(buff, "%s %s", token, token);
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/:

"s: String of characters. This will read subsequent characters until a whitespace is found (whitespace characters are considered to be blank, newline and tab)."

You're using only 1 %s so it wwould NEVER return more than 1. Anyway, you already call sscanf inside the while condition, no need to call it again inside the while body.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use scanf to get rid of your issue. You could use the `strtok` function, defined in `string.h` instead. So, an answer to your question could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buff[50];
    char *token;
    int number=0;

    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {

        if((token = strtok (buff, " ")) != NULL) {
            ++number;
            while ((token = strtok (NULL, " ")) != NULL)
                ++number;
        }
        if(number == 2)
            printf("Current line has two tokens\n");
        else printf("current line has %d tokens\n", number);

        number=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char buff[50];
char token1[50], token2[50];

while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL)
{
    if( sscanf(buff, "%s %s", token1, token2) == 2 )
    {
        printf("%s ", buff);
    }
}
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you print the buff at the end, it prints out the whole input instead of only two tokens